# How to make navigation inside react-native-drawer using react-native-router-flux

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux, react-native-drawer

I have created drawer using `react-native-drawer`. drawer View contains `ListView`. Whenever click the `renderRow` method need to show navigation inside the drawer itself instead of top of the `Welcome` screen stack.

Right now: [Check the Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcdbL.png)

Expected: 
[want to achieve something like this - Multi Level Menu](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/fJsrU4CEjCGadQIlmTfPOB5OLYX2oXYkMjUgbEdb2lvv3bz6UQClUPzPJCxX2Y7f/file)

**File:** Component/welcome.js

```
render(){
  var settingPanel = <Setting closeDrawer={ () => {
    this.drawer.close();
  }} />
  return(
     <Drawer
       ref={c => this.drawer = c}
       type='overlay'
       content={settingPanel}
       ...>
        <Home />
     </Drawer>
  );
}
```

**File:** Component/setting.js

```
render(){
  return(
    <ListView
     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
     renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
    />
  );
}

renderRow (items) {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.rowText}>{items.name}</Text>
            <ImageButton onPress={Actions.trans()} img={fb} />
        </View>
    )
};
```

Its navigating on top of the `Welcome` screen. I need to navigate on the drawer itself. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

from it's documentation  [here](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/blob/master/README.md#opening--closing-the-drawer-programmatically)

options to open drawer
Three options:

1. Use the open prop (controlled mode):

   ```
   <Drawer
     open={true}
   ```
2. Using the Drawer Ref:

   ```
   // assuming ref is set up on the drawer as (ref) => this._drawer = ref
   onPress={() => {this._drawer.open()}}
   ```
3. Using Context

   ```
   contextTypes = {drawer: React.PropTypes.object}
   // later...
   this.context.drawer.open()
   ```

then to navigate to another component using react-native-router-flux you can add a `TouchableOpacity` component insted of `<home />` then in `onPress` add `actions.home()` 
and home is the key of react-native-router-flux scene component

Comment: I can able to open & close the drawer. That is not the problem. Plz see the SS. How can I navigate to another component inside the drawer?

Comment: using `TochableOpacity` or any button component I have updated the answer